# Creation timestamp for an embedded document in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, pymongo, updates

My document structure looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": <unique id>,
    "embeddedDocs": 
                   {
                    1: {field1: value1, 
                        _creation_timestamp: <time when doc 1 was created>}, 
                    2: {field1: value2, 
                        _creation_timestamp: <time when doc 2 was created>}
                   }
   }
```

I want to the embedded documents to have a "creation timestamp" i.e., the time when the embedded document was created.

1. I cannot use an `upsert` because everytime I do it, the `_creation_timestamp` gets updated.
2. I cannot use `setOnInsert` for `_creation_timestamp` because I would have to follow that with a `set` for updating `field1` which would overwrite the `_creation_timestamp`.
3. I cannot use both `set` and `setOnInsert` in the same update operation because I get an error saying `"Cannot update embeddedDocs.1 and embeddedDocs.1._creation_timestamp at the same time"`

Comment: It sounds unclear about what you wish to achieve. Can you update your question with what you have tried and your expected result. It would help seek more attention.

Comment: Update: I want the embedded documents to have a "creation timestamp" i.e., the time when the embedded document was created.

Comment: It was a clear ask. "Edit the question with the code you are attempting that is giving you the problem". You haven't done that. It may also help to explain what your general purpose is as well, since there is likely a better way to do what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you stuffing the documents inside a pseudo-array in a larger document? You may profit by making the subdocuments in the array into the members of the collection. If you need to identify the documents as part of some group, you can put a family id on them.

```
{
    "_id": <unique id>,
    "field1" : "value1", 
    "_creation_timestamp" : <time when doc 1 was created>}
    "family_id" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : <unique id>,
    "field1" : "value2",
    "_creation_timestamp" : <time when doc 2 was created>
    "family_id" : 0
}
```

To add the created timestamp, just put include as a field when you insert:

```
db.collection.insert({ "_id" : <unique id>, "field1" : "value3", "_creation_timestamp" : ISODate(), "family_id" : 0 })
```

If you do keep the embedded structure, you also most likely do not want to use the pseudo-array structure of putting the documents as values with the keys being an index. It will make it hard to search on conditions on subdocuments. Use an array instead:

```
{
    "_id": <unique id>,
    "embeddedDocs": [
        { "field1" : "value1", "_creation_timestamp" : <time when doc 1 was created> }, 
        { "field1" : "value2", "_creation_timestamp" : <time when doc 2 was created> }
    ]
}
```

To add a created timestamp to this structure, just include the timestamp when you push to the document:

```
db.collection.update({ "_id" : <unique id> }, { "$push" : { "embeddedDocs" : { "field1" : "value3", "_creation_timestamp" : ISODate() } } })
```